# Why isn't Oracle throwing an error message due to missing GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

I'm on Oracle 11g and rather perplexed how the 3rd query can even compile below.  Shouldn't this throw an ORA-00937 error?  Can anyone else reproduce this or explain how or why Oracle is ignoring the lack of a GROUP BY clause in the inline view?  (it does throw on error just running the subquery by itself though)

```
DROP TABLE ZZZ_DELETE_ME;
CREATE TABLE ZZZ_DELETE_ME
(
contract NUMBER(6),
lives INTEGER
 );

 INSERT INTO ZZZ_DELETE_ME (contract,lives) VALUES (123456,100);
 INSERT INTO ZZZ_DELETE_ME (contract,lives) VALUES (123456,50);
 INSERT INTO ZZZ_DELETE_ME (contract,lives) VALUES (123457,100);
 INSERT INTO ZZZ_DELETE_ME (contract,lives) VALUES (123457,50);
 INSERT INTO ZZZ_DELETE_ME (contract,lives) VALUES (123458,100);
 INSERT INTO ZZZ_DELETE_ME (contract,lives) VALUES (123458,50);
 INSERT INTO ZZZ_DELETE_ME (contract,lives) VALUES (123459,100);
 INSERT INTO ZZZ_DELETE_ME (contract,lives) VALUES (123459,50);

 -- query 1 returns 100 for each record (which makes sense)
 SELECT contract, SUM(MAX_LIVES) TOTAL_LIVES
 FROM 
     (
     SELECT contract, MAX(lives) MAX_LIVES
     FROM ZZZ_DELETE_ME 
     GROUP BY contract
     )
 GROUP BY contract;

 -- query 2 returns 400 (which makes sense)
 SELECT SUM(MAX_LIVES) TOTAL_LIVES
 FROM 
     (
     SELECT contract, MAX(lives) MAX_LIVES
     FROM ZZZ_DELETE_ME 
     GROUP BY contract
     );

 -- query 3 returns 100 (but why?  Shouldn't this throw an error?)
 SELECT SUM(MAX_LIVES) TOTAL_LIVES
 FROM 
     (
     SELECT contract, MAX(lives) MAX_LIVES
     FROM ZZZ_DELETE_ME 
     -- THERE'S NO GROUP BY HERE!
     );
```

Comment: Query 3 is indeed invalid. Should raise an error!

Comment: You're right, it does seem to work on 11g, but it fails in 12.1.0.2. I'd guess that since `contract` isn't referenced in the outer query, it's being silently removed by the compiler. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/532706/1/0

Comment: @kfinity . . . That is a good explanation.  Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was Oracle bug 5520732, fixed in release 11.2.  If you have an Oracle Support account, you can read all about it.

To confirm, you can change your query to

```
SELECT SUM(MAX_LIVES) TOTAL_LIVES
FROM 
   (
   SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ contract, MAX(lives) MAX_LIVES
   FROM ZZZ_DELETE_ME 
   -- THERE'S NO GROUP BY HERE!
   );
```

... and you should get the expected error.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c produces ORA-00937 in that case, I've tested.